# How to make multi form without next button?

Tags: javascript, unbounce

I want to make multi step form without `next` button. If anyone select any radio button then it will go to next step. I have tried below way with `next` button how can to that without next button. Something like **[THIS.](https://moneysavingadvisors.co.uk/lp/will-writing/)**

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/kimmobrunfeldt/progressbar.js/1.0.0/dist/progressbar.js"></script>

<script>
  (function() {
    // Update the following IDs with your own button IDs
    var backButton = document.getElementById('lp-pom-button-481');
    var nextButton = document.getElementById('lp-pom-button-478'); //lp-pom-button-478
    var showProgressBar = false;

    var submitButton = document.querySelector('.lp-pom-form .lp-pom-button');
    var formContainer = document.querySelector('.lp-element .lp-pom-form');
    var currentField = 0;
    var allFields = document.getElementsByClassName('lp-pom-form-field');
    var errorSpan = document.createElement('span');

    for (i = 0; i < allFields.length; i++) {
      allFields[i].classList.add('hide');
      allFields[i].style.top = '0px';
    }

    backButton.classList.add('hide');
    submitButton.classList.add('hide');

    allFields[0].classList.remove('hide');

    if (allFields[0].querySelector('input')) {
      allFields[0].querySelector('input').focus();
    }

    errorSpan.classList.add('hide');
    errorSpan.style.color = 'red';
    errorSpan.style.position = 'absolute';
    var labelHeight;
    if (allFields[0].querySelector('label')) {
      labelHeight = allFields[0].querySelector('label').clientHeight;
    } else {
      labelHeight = 25;
    }
    errorSpan.style.top = '+' + '27' + 'px';
    formContainer.appendChild(errorSpan);

    if (showProgressBar) {
      var progressContainer = document.createElement('div');
      progressContainer.id = 'container';
      formContainer.appendChild(progressContainer);

      var bar = new ProgressBar.Line(container, {
        strokeWidth: 4,
        easing: 'easeInOut',
        duration: 1400,
        color: '#FFEA82',
        trailColor: '#eee',
        trailWidth: 1,
        svgStyle: { width: '100%', height: '100%' },
        from: { color: '#FFEA82' },
        to: { color: '#74D16A' },
        text: {
          style: {
            // Text color.
            // Default: same as stroke color (options.color)
            color: '#fff',
            position: 'absolute',
            right: '0',
            top: '30px',
            padding: 0,
            margin: 0,
            transform: null,
          },
          autoStyleContainer: false,
        },
        step: function(state, bar) {
          bar.setText(currentField + 1 + ' of ' + allFields.length);
          bar.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
        },
      });
    }

    function nextEvent() {
      allFields[currentField].classList.add('hide');

      currentField += 1;
      allFields[currentField].classList.remove('hide');
      if (allFields[currentField].querySelector('input')) {
        allFields[currentField].querySelector('input').focus();
      }

      if (currentField > 0) {
        backButton.classList.remove('hide');
      }

      if (currentField === allFields.length - 1) {
        submitButton.classList.remove('hide');
        nextButton.classList.add('hide');
      }

      updateProgress();
    }

    function backEvent() {
      allFields[currentField].classList.add('hide');
      submitButton.classList.add('hide');

      currentField -= 1;
      allFields[currentField].classList.remove('hide');
      if (allFields[currentField].querySelector('input')) {
        allFields[currentField].querySelector('input').focus();
      }
      if (currentField === 0) {
        backButton.classList.add('hide');
        nextButton.classList.remove('hide');
      }
      if (currentField <= allFields.length - 1) {
        nextButton.classList.remove('hide');
      }

      updateProgress();
    }

    function currentFieldInvalid() {
      var invalidInput = allFields[currentField].querySelector(':invalid');

      if (invalidInput) {
        errorSpan.textContent = invalidInput.validationMessage;
      }

      return Boolean(invalidInput);
    }

    function updateProgress() {
      if (showProgressBar) {
        var barSize = (currentField + 1) / allFields.length;
        bar.animate(barSize); // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
      }
    }

    updateProgress();

    nextButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (currentFieldInvalid()) {
        if (allFields[currentField].querySelector('input')) {
          allFields[currentField].querySelector('input').classList.add('hasError');
        } else {
          allFields[currentField].children[1].classList.add('hasError');
        }

        errorSpan.classList.remove('hide');
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        if (allFields[currentField].querySelector('input')) {
          allFields[currentField].querySelector('input').classList.remove('hasError');
        } else {
          allFields[currentField].children[1].classList.remove('hasError');
        }

        errorSpan.classList.add('hide');
        nextEvent();
      }
    });

    backButton.addEventListener('click', backEvent);

    submitButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (currentFieldInvalid()) {
        if (allFields[currentField].querySelector('input')) {
          allFields[currentField].querySelector('input').classList.add('hasError');
        } else {
          allFields[currentField].children[1].classList.add('hasError');
        }

        errorSpan.classList.remove('hide');
        e.preventDefault();
      } else {
        if (allFields[currentField].querySelector('input')) {
          allFields[currentField].querySelector('input').classList.remove('hasError');
        } else {
          allFields[currentField].children[1].classList.remove('hasError');
        }

        errorSpan.classList.add('hide');
      }
    });

    document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
      var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

      // Enter key
      if (keyCode === 13 && currentField < allFields.length - 1) {
        if (currentFieldInvalid()) {
          if (allFields[currentField].querySelector('input')) {
            allFields[currentField].querySelector('input').classList.add('hasError');
          } else {
            allFields[currentField].children[1].classList.add('hasError');
          }

          errorSpan.classList.remove('hide');
          e.preventDefault();
        } else {
          if (allFields[currentField].querySelector('input')) {
            allFields[currentField].querySelector('input').classList.remove('hasError');
          } else {
            allFields[currentField].children[1].classList.remove('hasError');
          }

          errorSpan.classList.add('hide');
          e.preventDefault();
          nextEvent();
        }
      } else if (keyCode === 13 && currentField === allFields.length - 1) {
        if (currentFieldInvalid()) {
          if (allFields[currentField].querySelector('input')) {
            allFields[currentField].querySelector('input').classList.add('hasError');
          } else {
            allFields[currentField].children[1].classList.add('hasError');
          }

          errorSpan.classList.remove('hide');
          e.preventDefault();
        } else {
          if (allFields[currentField].querySelector('input')) {
            allFields[currentField].querySelector('input').classList.remove('hasError');
          } else {
            allFields[currentField].children[1].classList.remove('hasError');
          }

          errorSpan.classList.add('hide');
        }
      }

      if (keyCode === 37) {
        // Left key
        if (currentField > 0) {
          backEvent();
        }
      } else if (keyCode === 39) {
        // Right key
        if (currentField < allFields.length - 1) {
          if (currentFieldInvalid()) {
            if (allFields[currentField].querySelector('input')) {
              allFields[currentField].querySelector('input').classList.add('hasError');
            } else {
              allFields[currentField].children[1].classList.add('hasError');
            }

            errorSpan.classList.remove('hide');
            e.preventDefault();
          } else {
            if (allFields[currentField].querySelector('input')) {
              allFields[currentField].querySelector('input').classList.remove('hasError');
            } else {
              allFields[currentField].children[1].classList.remove('hasError');
            }

            errorSpan.classList.add('hide');
            nextEvent();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  })();

</script>
```

Comment: you can listen to `onchange` event so when it is triggered you go to next form

Comment: Could you show a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it

```js
document.querySelector("form").onchange = function(e) {
  var currentFormPage = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
  console.log(e.target.name + ": " + e.target.value);
  if(currentFormPage.nextElementSibling) {
    currentFormPage.classList.add("hidden");
    currentFormPage.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("hidden");
  }
};
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .hidden {
    display:none;
  }
  form {
    width: 400px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px lightgreen, 0px 0px 1px lightgreen;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .radio-choice {
    display: flex;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px  2px #ccc;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  input[type='email'], input[type='button'] {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #ccc
  }
  input[type='email'] {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    height: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }
  input[type='button'] {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .radio-choice input {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 15px;
  }
  form h2 {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
```

```html
<form>
  <h2>Free Google Ads Audit!</h2>
  <div>
    <h4>What's your monthly ads budget?</h4>
    <label class="radio-choice" style="display: none"><input type="radio" name="whats_your_monthly_ads_budget" value="" checked></label>
    <label class="radio-choice"><input type="radio" name="whats_your_monthly_ads_budget" value="2000-10000">2,000 - 10,000</label>
    <label class="radio-choice"><input type="radio" name="whats_your_monthly_ads_budget" value="11000-50000">11,000 - 50,000</label>
    <label class="radio-choice"><input type="radio" name="whats_your_monthly_ads_budget" value="51000-100000">51,000 - 100,000</label>
    <label class="radio-choice"><input type="radio" name="whats_your_monthly_ads_budget" value="+100000">100,000+</label>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h4>What are your Goal(s)?</h4>
    <label class="radio-choice" style="display: none"><input type="radio" name="what_are_your_goals" value="" checked></label>
    <label class="radio-choice"><input type="radio" name="what_are_your_goals" value="Lead Generation">Lead Generation</label>
    <label class="radio-choice"><input type="radio" name="what_are_your_goals" value="Brand Awareness">Brand Awareness</label>
    <label class="radio-choice"><input type="radio" name="what_are_your_goals" value="Online Sales">Online Sales</label>
    <label class="radio-choice"><input type="radio" name="what_are_your_goals" value="Sign-ups">Sign-ups</label>
  </div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <h4>Success! You qualify for a Free Google Ads Audit, enter your email to confirm!</h4>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Company Email">
    <input type="button" name="email" value="Download">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: great! Could you tell me how can i get `ID` of `checked` radio `button`?

Comment: You don't need the `ID` as you can see in my case there are no IDs for radio buttons, instead I get the name and the value of the checked one since that's all what matters, and I'm logging them to the console so you can see that.

Comment: You show it's for another markup style but i need to work with this https://jsfiddle.net/7udpwbq2/ JS.